# Asymptotic properties for LASSO in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, references, lasso, asymptotics

I am trying to find a paper or book that gives the asymptotic properties for the LASSO for logistic regression.

Anyone has any suggestions please?

Comment: Well, for Adaptive LASSO, [the authors of this paper](http://users.stat.umn.edu/~zouxx019/Papers/adalasso.pdf) prove the oracle properties for GLM models, which includes the logistic regression.

Comment: @Nutle - I had a look at this paper and mainly it is on the adaptive lasso not the classical lasso

Comment: True, so I just added this as a comment, in case you might be interested. Adaptive LASSO in most cases should perform better or similar to the classic LASSO, so it's worth a look.

Comment: @Nutle - Yes for sure and it was worth the look because I seen some general properties of the classical LASSO, however, I did not manage to find for the GLM setting